# how to cast drawable image to imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am zooming a drawable image and then dragging it with the following codes. The image is getting zoomed but throwing a CLASSCASTEXCEPTION  on dragging. The code for dragging image is as:

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event)

    {


        ImageView v =(ImageView) view;// here the cast error occurs

        v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

         //zoomControler+=10;
        // invalidate();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
              savedMatrix.set(matrix);
              start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
           Log.d("mode=DRAG", null);
              mode = DRAG;
              break;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                  if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger
                     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                     if (v.getLeft() >= -392){
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                     }
                  } 
                }

           // Perform the transformation
           v.setImageMatrix(matrix);

           return true; // indicate event was handled


         }}

}
```

Please help me on this as  I am new to android.
Thanks in adv

Comment: What is the actual class of the View that is being passed to onTouch()? That will give a hint of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not set the touch listener on the right view. This will only work if the listener is attached to an ImageView.